# I want to make custom array shuffle in php with respect to integer

Tags: php

Looking the function below:

```
function CustomShuffle($arr, $para){
............................
............................
return $array;
}
```

Suppose this is an array:

```
$array = array("red","green","blue","yellow","purple");
```

looking output something like below (May be different ordered but must be same for same integer parameter)

```
$result = CustomShuffle($array, 10);  
// output: array("blue","purple","yellow","red","green")  same

$result = CustomShuffle($array, 12);  
// output: array("purple","yellow","red","green","blue")

$result = CustomShuffle($array, 10);  
// output: array("blue","purple","yellow","red","green") same


$result = CustomShuffle($array, 7);  
// output: array("blue","yellow","purple","red","green")
```

Simply, array will be shuffled with respect to integer parameter but output will be same for same parameter. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, how it happens does come down to a desired implementation and how many permutations you wish to allow. A very naive method of accomplishing this is to have a loop that runs `$para` times within `CustomShuffle` that would [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) an element then [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) that same element. This method would only give you `count($array)` possible outcomes, meaning numbers congruent modulo `count($array)` would produce the same result.

The optimal algorithm would allow you to take advantage of the maximum combinations, which would be `gmp_fact(count($array))`, or simply the factorial of the length of the input array. There is no possible way to achieve more unique combinations than this value, so no matter what algorithm you design, you will always have a constraint on the value of `$para` until you eventually encounter a combination already seen.

Comment: What isn't working? I did not include any code here to be working, only references. If something isn't working in your code you need to edit your question to express that.

Comment: I have understood your answer and have already tried similar thing. http://www.englishact.com/Permutation/index.php?permutation=notwork#result    : here I tried permutation which is not effective way to work with. This will make my server slow for long array (1000+ values). So using permutation method this will not solve my problem. Actually I need effective method that can be applicable in live project.

Comment: Your question was not how to design such an algorithm, it was if it was possible to do so. Which I answered. You need to either change your question or ask a new one.